# How to generate a random binary matrix where only one bit in each row has value 1?

Tags: matlab, matrix, random

I want to use MATLAB to generate a random binary matrix `A` (n x m) which satisfies a condition:

Each row contains one position with value `1`. Other positions are value `0`. The position having `1` value is random position.

I tried this code

```
   n=5;m=10; 
   %% A = randi([0 1], n,m);
   A=zeros(n,m);
   for i=1:n
       rand_pos=randperm(m);
       pos_one=rand_pos(1); % random possition of 1 value
       A(i,pos_one)=1;
   end
```

Is it correct?

Comment: *Is it correct?* Well, did you try running it?

Comment: I run it and it give me a random binary matrix as above condition. I am not sure my code is correct or not

Comment: I run it, and it meats the condition that each **row** contains one position with value 1.

Comment: Yes. I may be mistaken between row and column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution works, but it is inefficient.
You are using `randperm` to create a vector (array), and then use only the first element of the vector.
You can use `randi` to create a scalar (single element) instead:

```
n=5;m=10; 
A=zeros(n,m);
for i=1:m
    %rand_pos gets a random number in range [1, n].
    rand_pos = randi([1, n]);
    A(rand_pos, i)=1;
end
```

---

You can also use the following "vectorized" solution:

```
rand_pos_vec = randi([1, n], 1, m);
A(sub2ind([n, m], rand_pos_vec, 1:m)) = 1;
```

The above solution:

- Creates a vector of random values in range [1, n].
- Use `sub2ind` to convert "row index" to "matrix index".
- Place 1 in "matrix index".

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line using [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`randi`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html):

```
A = double(bsxfun(@eq, 1:m, randi(n, n, 1)));
```

This compares the row vector `[1 2 ... m]` with an `n`×`1` random vector of values from `1` to `n`. The comparison is done element-wise with singleton expansion. For each row, exactly one of the values of `[1 2 ... m]` equals that in the random vector.